# fade out div, fade in another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, replacewith

I'm looking to fade out (or remove?) the text in a div and then fadein or show the text in a different div on a button click. I'm having some trouble writing the jQuery, would really appreciate any advice or help.

Should I actively remove the content of the div? Or use replaceWith()? And should I set the display to none in the css?

I'd really appreciate any help as well as any general advice about my code.

Here's how it's looking:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <header>
                    <h1 class=""><a href="index.html">##</a></h1>
                    <h3 class="">Educational Consultant and Tutor</h3>
                    <ul class="topul">
                        <li>
                            <button id="home">
                                <p>Home</p>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button id="aboutme">
                                <p>About Me</p>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button id="tuition">
                                <p>Tuition</p>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button id="consultancy">
                                <p>Consultancy</p>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button id="testimonials">
                                <p>Testimonials</p>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button id="contact">
                                <p>Contact</p>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="secondcontainer">
        <div class="row" id="mainstuff">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center " id="bigimage">
                <img src="images/Raph%20edited.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 p-4 " id="textarea">
                <div id="texts" class="vertical ">
                        <p>I am an experienced 11+ tutor currently living and working in London. Former pupils have been accepted to Dulwich College, Latymer Upper, Godolphin and Latymer, St Paul’s Girls’ School, Wetherby Senior School, The Harrodian and Queen’s Gate.</p>
                        <p>After graduating from Cambridge in 2011, I moved to Moscow, Russia, where I worked as a private tutor for three years, preparing pupils for entrance to London schools. As well as helping my pupils with their academic studies, I also supervised their music practice (piano, singing and drums), introduced them to basic computer programming blah blah I returned to the UK only to promptly leave again, and in 2016 I travelled through South America and Australia, teaching pupils English and maths in Rio de Janeiro, Buenos Aires, Rosario, Mendoza and Brisbane. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="vertical " id="aboutmetext">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p id="finalone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="vertical " id="tuitiontext">
                    <p>TUITION TEXTOadipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                    <p id="finalone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var current = "#texts";
    console.log(current);

    $("#aboutme").click(function(){
        $(current).remove();
        $("#aboutmetext").show();
        current = "#aboutmetext";
        console.log(current);
    });

console.log(current);

    $("#tuition").click(function(){
        $(current).remove();
        $("#tuitiontext").show();
        current = "#tuitiontext";
        console.log(current);
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you exatly wants, but try this. it fade the text that corrospond with the button in and fades the others out.

```
$("#aboutme,#tuition").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id") + "text"
  $(current).fadeOut();
  $("#" + id).fadeIn();
  current = "#" + id;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var current = "#texts";

  $("#aboutme,#tuition").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id") + "text"
    $(current).fadeOut();
    $("#" + id).fadeIn();
    current = "#" + id;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <header>
        <h1 class=""><a href="index.html">##</a></h1>
        <h3 class="">Educational Consultant and Tutor</h3>
        <ul class="topul">
          <li>
            <button id="home">
                                <p>Home</p>
                            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="aboutme">
                                <p>About Me</p>
                            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="tuition">
                                <p>Tuition</p>
                            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="consultancy">
                                <p>Consultancy</p>
                            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="testimonials">
                                <p>Testimonials</p>
                            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="contact">
                                <p>Contact</p>
                            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="secondcontainer">
  <div class="row" id="mainstuff">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center " id="bigimage">
      <img src="images/Raph%20edited.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 p-4 " id="textarea">
      <div id="texts" class="vertical ">
        <p>I am an experienced 11+ tutor currently living and working in London. Former pupils have been accepted to Dulwich College, Latymer Upper, Godolphin and Latymer, St Paul’s Girls’ School, Wetherby Senior School, The Harrodian and Queen’s Gate.</p>
        <p>After graduating from Cambridge in 2011, I moved to Moscow, Russia, where I worked as a private tutor for three years, preparing pupils for entrance to London schools. As well as helping my pupils with their academic studies, I also supervised
          their music practice (piano, singing and drums), introduced them to basic computer programming blah blah I returned to the UK only to promptly leave again, and in 2016 I travelled through South America and Australia, teaching pupils English
          and maths in Rio de Janeiro, Buenos Aires, Rosario, Mendoza and Brisbane. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="vertical " id="aboutmetext">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p id="finalone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="vertical " id="tuitiontext">
        <p>TUITION TEXTOadipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
        <p id="finalone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illum culpa assumenda ratione sunt tempora obcaecati nobis sed nemo omnis eligendi odio aut quia, debitis necessitatibus quisquam, provident aspernatur quam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fade out by animating the CSS `opacity` property. When the animation finishes, then I would show the text of the different element.

```
//fade out
$(selector).animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, function(){
  //show different element's text
  $(differentElement).show();
  });
```

```js
$('#first').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('p').animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, function(){
    $('#text p').show();
    });
  });
```

```css
#text p{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first">
<p>Hello World</p>
</button>
<div id="text">
<p>Lots of text content here</p>
</div>
```